# Flutter: Erro ao adicionar mais de 3 itens em um Listview

Tags: android, listview, dart, flutter

Olá, todas as `Listview` do meu aplicativo em Flutter se adicionar mais de 3 itens ocorre a Exception abaixo:

> I/flutter (13259): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter (13259): The following assertion was thrown building
>   I/flutter (13259): RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#fd1f4](state:
>   I/flutter (13259): RawGestureDetectorState#a263f(gestures: , behavior: opaque)):
>   I/flutter (13259): 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 263 pos 16:
>   I/flutter (13259): 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true.

Depois dessa Exception, tento ir para outra tela e o erro a seguir aparece na minha Listview, depois expande para toda a tela!

> I/flutter ( 7826): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 1772 pos 12: '_elements.contains(element)': is not true.

[image: exception]

Alguem já passou por isso e pode me ajudar?

Código Widget:

```dart
 @override
  void dispose() {
    listViewController.removeListener(_scrollListener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
      key: _scaffoldstate,
     body: (_listaTela.length == 0)
      ? new AppLayout(
        navBar: NavBar(
          title: "$_titulo",
        ),
        widget: Column(
          //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 15.0,
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 35.0, right: 15.0),
                    child: Container(
                        width: 45.0,
                        height: 45.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle),
                        child: new Icon(Icons.shopping_basket)),
                  ),
                  Text("$_titulo",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 25.0, right: 25.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 15.0),
              child: Divider(
                height: 1.0,
              ),
            ),
            // sem itens
            Offstage(
              offstage: !_semItens,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.list,
                    size: 50.0,
                  ),
                  Text('Sem itens'),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _resetLista();
                    },
                    child: Text('Atualizar'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // loading
            Offstage(
              offstage: !_ocupado,
              child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            ),
                  ],
                ),
              ) 
              : new AppLayout(
        navBar: NavBar(
          title: "$_titulo",
        ),
        widget: Column(
          //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 15.0,
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 35.0, right: 15.0),
                    child: Container(
                        width: 45.0,
                        height: 45.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
                            shape: BoxShape.circle),
                        child: new Icon(Icons.shopping_basket)),
                  ),
                  Text("$_titulo",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 25.0, right: 25.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 15.0),
              child: Divider(
                height: 1.0,
              ),
            ),
            // sem itens
            Offstage(
              offstage: !_semItens,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.list,
                    size: 50.0,
                  ),
                  Text('Sem itens'),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _resetLista();
                    },
                    child: Text('Atualizar'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // loading
            Offstage(

 Flexible(
              child: ClipRect(
                child: RefreshIndicator(
                  onRefresh: _resetLista,

                  child: ListView(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 4.0,
                      right: 4.0,
                    ),
                      controller: listViewController,
                      children: _listaTela.map((it) {
                        return Dismissible(
                          background: Container(color: Colors.red,),
                          key: ValueKey("remover"),
                          onDismissed: (direction){
                            setState((){
                              _removerItem(it);
                            });
                          },
                          child: ListTile(
                          onTap: () {
                            _itemSel(it, _listaTela.indexOf(it));
                          },
                          title: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[

                              Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 40.0,
                                    width: 50.0,
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.label,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      size: 30.0,
                                    ),
                                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                                  )),
                              Flexible(
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              bottom: 4.0),
                                          child: Text(
                                            it.produto.descricao.toString(),
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 15.0,
                                                letterSpacing: 1.0,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                            maxLines: 1,
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              bottom: 4.0),
                                          child: Text(
                                            it.quantidade.toString(),
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 15.0,
                                              letterSpacing: 1.0,
                                            ),
                                            maxLines: 1,
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                        );
                      }).toList()),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Text(
                      '$_lblTot',
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
        animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
        children: [
          SpeedDialChild(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            label: "Adicionar item",
            onTap: () {
              _add();
            }, 
            ),
            SpeedDialChild(
            child: Icon(Icons.send),
            label: "Enviar pedido",
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            onTap: () {
              _enviar();
            } 
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Mostre o código que você fez.

Comment: Sem o código não é possível analisarmos

Comment: Adicionei o código do ListView, obrigado desde já.

Comment: Seria interessante um exemplo que fosse possível reproduzir, pegar o seu código e executar.. Se não for possível passar, eu recomendaria ir removendo Widget por Widget da árvore para identificar onde está o problema.

Comment: @JulioHenriqueBitencourt Vou criar um código que de para reproduzir, obrigado.

Comment: @DenerPortela show! Facilitará a análise.

Comment: @JulioHenriqueBitencourt Coloquei o projeto no Github: https://github.com/denerportela/flutter_listview_bug_itens 

1. Baixar o projeto.
2. Executar.
3. Clicar no Botão Menu Flutuante
4. Clicar no botão de +

Após o 3º clique o erro vai aparecer!

Comment: Se a resposta ajudou/respondeu a sua pergunta, marque ela como aceita.

Answer (score 0):

Dei uma olhada no projeto que você colocou no GitHub. Seu código está confuso, desorganizado e em alguns locais fora de formatação.

Ao rodar já ocorre o erro:

> E/flutter (21316): Receiver: null E/flutter (21316): Tried calling:
>   length E/flutter (21316): #0      Object.noSuchMethod
>   (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5) E/flutter (21316): #1
>   _MyHomePageState._getData. (package:test_listview/main.dart:117:45)

Você está chamando o `lenght` em um objeto nulo, você precisa rever sua lógica ao utilizar programação assíncrona.

De fato, após adicionar os items em seu exemplo ocorre outro erro. Mas com certeza se você rever a lógica da sua tela, reconstruir o exemplo novamente passo a passo, e seguir os princípios de qualidade vai conseguir identificar onde você está errando.

O problema não está na `ListView`, se você debugar perceberá, está na estrutura de Widgets que você está usando.

Recomendo:

- Organizar o código, separar melhor em métodos/Widgets as responsabilidades, reconstruir esse seu código do zero.
- Seguir boas práticas gerais de codificação em Dart, nomenclatura de variáveis, formatação de código (use a IDE com o plugin para formatação), organização dos arquivos em pacote, etc.
- Ir adicionando etapa por etapa e verificar em que momento exatamente o erro começa a ocorrer.
- Não commitar o `.idea` para o repositório versionado, isso é uma configuração da IDE local.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas de programação Julio, como estou começando vai ajudar muito não apenas neste projeto como em outros. Realmente o principal problema aqui é a organização e boas práticas. Mas que vou adquirir com o tempo ou em um curso de programação. Um tempo infelizmente que eu não tenho agora pelo prazo apertado. Vou ver o que consigo. Muito obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: Claro, todos fomos e somos iniciantes a todo momento. Citei as boas práticas e organização porque elas ajudam a gente a entender melhor o que está acontecendo em nosso código e encontrar onde estão os problemas, o que está fazendo ocorrer determinado erro. E claro, facilitam quando se trabalha em time e outra pessoa também precisa entender o seu código. Se tiver alguma dúvida específica de algum comportamento não deixe de abrir pergunta aqui :)